# Is there any free email provider with Internationalized Domain Name (IDN)?

Tags: email, smtp, ascii, non-ascii-characters, idn

I just added support for recipients with IDN in an application that I'm building, but I cannot properly test this feature without having a domain with non-ASCII characters.

Is there any free service where I can get a mail address with internationalized characters in the domain name? I wasn't able to find anything on the internet.

Lots of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of such things; a Thai organisation runs one, the government of Sri Lanka does, etc, but as far as I know there's noone that'll provide a free unicode email address for a worldwide audience. (The lankan one, for example, is for inhabitants of that state, which I guess excludes you.)

Google and Microsoft will do that for a small fee; you can add an IDN domain to your account and then send email to that domain. That'll give you addresses such as gul@grå.org (ASCII localpart, IDN domain) and you use gmail's catch-all address feature, gmail will also accept blå@grå.org (assuming grå.org is your domain, which it is not, because it's my domain).